# how to access the elements inside the third-party selector?

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I have a selector "own date picker" of the same package. It has a "div" containing "input", the code of which I need to change (css). How to change the third-party package code correctly? Modifying the code in "node_modules" is not correct and I can not change the class of that "input" in my project..

```
<own-date-picker>
  <div>
    <input>
  </div>
</own-date-picker>
```

But I write only "own-date-picker" selector and don't have access to input

Comment: would help if you reveal the name of that mysterious library you're using

Comment: https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker

Comment: I believe the class you're looking for is `.owl-datetime-input` - in your hosting component's css

Comment: it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Give some class name inside tag

`<own-date-picker class="myPicker">`

And then In CSS try like this

`.myPicker div input {
 Your changes here
}`

Comment: @Munna your answer is wrong. The component uses the default encapsulation mode `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` so your css would never be applied. You have to use ::ng-deep. https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation